# Cakephp object mapper?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have the following code in android to send to my cakephp server

```
val params = JSONObject()
val siteId = sharedPref.getInt("site_id", 0)
try {
    params.put("photo", encodeImage)
    params.put("lat", latitude)
    params.put("lng", longitude)
    params.put("status", status)
    params.put("site_id", siteId)
} catch (e: JSONException) {
    Log.e("JsonException", e.toString())
}
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@CameraActivity)
val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ROOT_URL + TRANSACTION,
        params, Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
//                        startActivity(myIntent)
}, Response.ErrorListener {
    Toast.makeText(this@CameraActivity, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}) {
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json")
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token) // Figure out a way to get JWT

        return headers
    }
}
```

And I have this code on cakephp controller to receive it

```
$transaction = $this->Transactions->newEntity();
if($this->request->is('post')){
  $transaction->lat = $this->request->getData('lat');
  $transaction->lng = $this->request->getData('lng');
  $photo = $this->request->getData('photo');
  $transaction->status = $this->request->getData('status');
  $decoded = base64_decode($photo);
  $transaction->employee_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
  $transaction->project_id = $this->Auth->user('project_id');
  $transaction->site_id = $this->request->getData('site_id');

  if ($this->Transactions->save($transaction)) {
    $this->Auth->logout();
    $this->set([
      'success' => true,
      '_serialize' => ['success']
    ]);
  }
}
```

The problem is on the server side I do not want to equate every request to a cakephp entity variable. Is there a way I can just do an object mapping so i do not need to do the unnecessary equating at the cakephp controller?

Comment: What do you mean by object mapping?

Comment: something similar to this https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: I assumed you did some googling, but is there any reason this wouldn't work: https://github.com/cweiske/jsonmapper *edit* that might not work since cake entities are a bit magic. One idea is to loop through the request and assign variables to $transaction via $transaction->{$name} = $value;